# How to solve a differential equation with time dependent parameters?

Tags: python, sympy, ode, differential-equations

I have a differential equation with time varying function W_at(t). How can I solve it using sympy's `dsolve` with initial conditions.

```
from sympy import *
init_printing(use_unicode=True)
theta_vr, theta_vd, theta_vo, t  = symbols('theta_vr theta_vd theta_vo t')
W_at = Function('W_at')
S_vt = Function('S_vt')
```

My differential equations as follows:

```
dSvt_dt = S_vt(t).diff(t)
CV = Eq(dSvt_dt, (1 + exp(-1 * theta_vr * theta_vd))/(1+ (exp((-1 * theta_vr * (W_at(t) - theta_vo + theta_vd)))) + ((exp( (theta_vr) * (W_at(t) - theta_vo)  - 1))) ))
```

I have used the following function from sympy to solve but it involves time varying W_at(t).

```
dsolve(CV, ics={S_vt(0):0})
```

How do I pass values of time varying function `W_at(t)` from csv file or spline curve? how do I get an array of values of values for S_vt at any given time interval.

Comment: It's not clear what you expect to get as output

Comment: @OscarBenjamin an array of values of values for `S_vt` at any given time interval.

Comment: If you want a numerical solution, you should use a numerical solver. It would be a happy coincidence if the long DE fits any of the implemented symbolic solution methods.

Comment: Your ODE and its solution have various symbols in. So when you say an array of "values" do you mean an array of symbolic expressions or are you expecting particular numbers like `12.34`?

Comment: @OscarBenjamin yes, the numbers like [12.34, 13.44, 15.0.....]

Comment: But then you would need to give numerical values for the parameters like `theta_vr` etc

Comment: Yes I do have all the numerical values for all symbols.